# Ошибка seeder-а при создании сущности

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs, prisma

При запуске nest-а seeder выдает ошибку:

```
Type '{ name: string; slug: string; description: string; price: number; images: string; category: { create: { name: string; slug: string; }; }; userId: number; reviews: { create: { title: string; raiting: number; text: string; user: { ...; }; }[]; }; 
}' is not assignable to type '(Without<ProductCreateInput, ProductUncheckedCreateInput> & ProductUncheckedCreateInput) | (Without<...> & ProductCreateInput)'.
  Type '{ name: string; slug: string; description: string; price: number; images: string; category: { create: { name: string; slug: string; }; }; userId: number; reviews: { create: { title: string; raiting: number; text: string; user: { ...; }; }[]; }; }' is not assignable to type 'Without<ProductUncheckedCreateInput, ProductCreateInput> & ProductCreateInput'.
    Type '{ name: string; slug: string; description: string; price: number; images: string; category: { create: { name: string; slug: string; }; }; userId: number; reviews: { create: { title: string; raiting: number; text: string; user: { ...; }; }[]; }; }' is not assignable to type 'Without<ProductUncheckedCreateInput, ProductCreateInput>'.
      Types of property 'userId' are incompatible.
        Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'never'.

21             data: {
               ~~~~

  node_modules/.prisma/client/index.d.ts:4015:5
    4015     data: XOR<ProductCreateInput, ProductUncheckedCreateInput>
             ~~~~
    The expected type comes from property 'data' which is declared here on type '{ select?: ProductSelect; include?: ProductInclude; data: (Without<ProductCreateInput, ProductUncheckedCreateInput> & ProductUncheckedCreateInput) | (Without<...> & ProductCreateInput); }'
```

Сам seeder:

```
import { faker } from '@faker-js/faker'
    import { PrismaClient, Product } from '@prisma/client'
    import * as dotenv from 'dotenv'
    
    dotenv.config()
    const prisma = new PrismaClient()
    
    const createProducts = async (quantity: number) => {
        const products: Product[] = []
    
        for(let i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
            const productName = faker.commerce.productName()
            const categoryName = faker.commerce.department()
    
            let imagesArray = []
            for (let i = 0; i < faker.datatype.number({min: 2, max: 6}); i++) {
                imagesArray.push(faker.image.imageUrl())
            }
    
            const product = await prisma.product.create({
                data: {
                    name: productName,
                    slug: faker.helpers.slugify(productName),
                    description: faker.commerce.productDescription(),
                    price: +faker.commerce.price(10, 999, 0),
                    images: JSON.stringify(imagesArray),
                    category: {
                        create: {
                            name: String(categoryName),
                            slug: faker.helpers.slugify(categoryName)
                        }
                    },
                    userId: 1,
                    reviews: {
                        create: [
                            {
                                title: faker.lorem.words(5),
                                raiting: faker.datatype.number({min: 1, max: 5}),
                                text: faker.lorem.words(15),
                                user: {
                                    connect: {
                                        id: 1
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                title: faker.lorem.words(10),
                                raiting: faker.datatype.number({min: 1, max: 5}),
                                text: faker.lorem.paragraph(),
                                user: {
                                    connect: {
                                        id: 1
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            })
    
            products.push(product)
        }
    
        console.log("Created"+quantity+"products")
    } 
    
    
    async function main() {
        console.log("Start seedeing...")
        await createProducts(10)
    }
    
    main()
        .catch(e => console.log(e))
        .finally(async () => {
            await prisma.$disconnect
        })
```

Prisma модель:

```
model User {
      id          Int         @id @default(autoincrement())
      createdAt   DateTime    @default(now()) @map("created_at")
      updatedAt   DateTime    @updatedAt @map("updated_at")
  
      email       String      @unique
      password    String
  
      name        String    
      surname     String  
      avatarPath  String      @default("./../uploads/unknown_user_avatar.png") @map("avatar_path")
  
      phone       String      @default("")
      reviews     Review[]
      favorites   Product[]
      orders      Order[]
  }
  
  model Category {
      id          Int         @id @default(autoincrement())
      createdAt   DateTime    @default(now()) @map("created_at")
      updatedAt   DateTime    @updatedAt @map("updated_at")
  

      name        String
      slug         String
  
      products    Product[]
  }
  
  model Product {
      id          Int         @id @default(autoincrement())
      createdAt   DateTime    @default(now()) @map("created_at")
      updatedAt   DateTime    @updatedAt @map("updated_at")
  
      name        String
      description String
      price       Int
      slug        String
      images      String
  
  
      categoryId  Int         @map("category_id")
      category    Category @relation(fields: [categoryId], references: [id])
  
      userId  Int         @map("user_id")
      user    User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  
      reviews     Review[]
  }
  
  enum EnumOrderStatus {
    PENDING
    PAYED
    SHIPPED
    DELIVERED
  }
  
  model Order {
      id          Int         @id @default(autoincrement())
      createdAt   DateTime    @default(now()) @map("created_at")
      updatedAt   DateTime    @updatedAt @map("updated_at")
  
      name        String
      status      EnumOrderStatus
  
  
      userId      Int         @map("user_id")
      user        User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  }
  
  model Review {
      id          Int         @id @default(autoincrement())
      createdAt   DateTime    @default(now()) @map("created_at")
      updatedAt   DateTime    @updatedAt @map("updated_at")    
  
      title       String
      text        String
      raiting     Int
  
      userId      Int @map("user_id")
      user        User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  
      productId     Int @map("product_id")
      product       Product @relation(fields: [productId], references: [id])
  }
```